# xna manual animation

Tags: animation, xna, xnanimation

i want to animate 3d model in xna programmatically  ,i tried to transform bones but nothing to happen only the whole model transform  not individual bones as i want 
i read the 3d model by basic model processor

so how i do this ?

and is there  any need to extended model processor like skinnedModelSample

please explain the steps

Answer (score 1):

The XNA Creator's Club education site has a perfect sample for what you're asking. The Simple Animation sample:
http://creators.xna.com/en-us/sample/simpleanimation

> This sample shows how to apply simple
>   program controlled rigid body
>   animation to a model rendered using
>   the XNA Framework.

Comment: thank you
i already have seen this project
in this project the tank parts move separately because the model consist of many meshs not only one mesh as a 3d character  model